# How to convert table to this in latex?

Tags: tables

[image]

I have following latex code, how to convert it to above format? Thx~

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table*}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Detailed performance comparision of our .}
  \resizebox{1.02\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
    \hline
    \hline
    Method & Building & Tree & Sky & Car & Sign & Road & Pedestrain & Fence & Pole  & Sidewalk & Bicyclist & Mean IOU(\%)  & FPS \\
    \hline
 SegNet-Basic & 67.4  & 92.6  & 81.9  & 37.5  & 80.0  & 60.8  & 68.3  & 82.4  & 80.1  & 81.6  & 31.1  & 65.9  &  FPS \\
 SegNet & 67.4  & 92.6  & 81.9  & 37.5  & 80.0  & 60.8  & 68.3  & 82.4  & 80.1  & 81.6  & 31.1  & 65.9  &  FPS \\
 ENet & 67.4  & 92.6  & 81.9  & 37.5  & 80.0  & 60.8  & 68.3  & 82.4  & 80.1  & 81.6  & 31.1  & 65.9  &  FPS \\
 BiseNet & 67.4  & 92.6  & 81.9  & 37.5  & 80.0  & 60.8  & 68.3  & 82.4  & 80.1  & 81.6  & 31.1  & 65.9  &  FPS \\
    \hline
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
    }
  \label{tab:align_voc}%
\end{table*}%
```

Comment: Off-topic: LaTeX places `table*` environments at the top of a page. Specifying `[htbp]` does nothing at all.

Answer (score 7):

If the question is how to get the horizontal lines and to rotate the texts, one answer may be "use `booktabs` for the rules and `graphicx` for the rotations".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Detailed performance comparision of our .}
  \resizebox{1.02\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{lccccccccccccccc}
    \toprule 
    \raisebox{3pt}{Method} & \rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{Building} &
    \rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{Tree} & \rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{Sky} &
    \rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{Car} & \rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{Sign} &
    \rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{Road} & \rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{Pedestrain} &
    \rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{Fence} & \rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{Pole } &
    \rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{Sidewalk} & \rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{Bicyclist}
    & \rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{Mean IOU(\%) } &
    \rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{FPS} \\
    \midrule
 SegNet-Basic & 67.4  & 92.6  & 81.9  & 37.5  & 80.0  & 60.8  & 68.3  & 82.4  & 80.1  & 81.6  & 31.1  & 65.9  &  FPS \\
 SegNet & 67.4  & 92.6  & 81.9  & 37.5  & 80.0  & 60.8  & 68.3  & 82.4  & 80.1  & 81.6  & 31.1  & 65.9  &  FPS \\
 ENet & 67.4  & 92.6  & 81.9  & 37.5  & 80.0  & 60.8  & 68.3  & 82.4  & 80.1  & 81.6  & 31.1  & 65.9  &  FPS \\
 BiseNet & 67.4  & 92.6  & 81.9  & 37.5  & 80.0  & 60.8  & 68.3  & 82.4  & 80.1  & 81.6  & 31.1  & 65.9  &  FPS \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    }
  \label{tab:align_voc}%
\end{table*}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks very much!!!!!!!!

Comment: what is the \***rule?  It means?  Can I use \hine?

Comment: @sunnpeng1996 It creates the horizontal lines. `booktabs` has different versions for the uppermost one, the lowermost one, and the others.

Comment: I see, thanks your thorough explanation! @ Schrödinger's cat